# ColdFusion 5 on MS Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-server-2008

Need to see if ColdFusion 5 will run on MS Server 2008 R2.

On a client's site that has ColdFusion 5(yes 5) and wants to move it to a MS Server with 2008 R2 and IIs 7.5 on it.  The one app that is on it is going away as is all ColdFusion.  So they do not want to invest in an upgrade. Simply not an option for them and they have made it clear.

2008 R2 Issues: CF 5 being 32-bit doesn't install for me.  Is there a way to make this happen?

IIS 7.5 I've read articles that CF 5 can be run on IIS 7.5 with compatibility mode turned on.  I don't think this will be the big hurdle.

The alternative is to keep in on the server it's on but for reasons this is the last alternative.

So for the most part I am looking for advise on running CF 5 on MS Server 2008 R2.

Thank you!

Comment: CF5 is 5 versions behind and over 10 years old. You're going to be hard pressed to find someone on CF5 and SQL Server 2008

Comment: As Dan said in his answer: get hold of a 32-bit machine or VM and *try it*. Advise the client that to investigate anything on a platform which is obsolete is going to take more time and materials than usual, and charge accordingly. If they don't want to pay for it, don't do it. Simple. This is just one of the costs of operating antiques: it costs more to maintain them.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/releasenotes/5/server/releasenotes_5.htm As @MattBusche commented, you get no support from either Adobe or Microsoft when running CodeFusion 5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just thinking, Scott. If the reason to not pay for an upgrade to a still-supported (and secure, and not unstable) version of ColdFusion is down to the licensing costs, have you considered Railo instead of ColdFusion? The software itself is free, but obviously you'd have to expect a bit of recoding for CFML which is no longer valid. There's not much of this, but more recent CFML implementations are - on the whole - less forgiving of dodgy code than old versions.

The benefit of taking this approach is that you'd be running software that is still maintained, and is up-to-date as far as security issues go. I think it's borderline negligent to be running outward-facing software which is so out of date, if I'm honest. Are your clients aware of the potential risks here?

Perhaps it's not an option, but maybe it is, so I thought I'd suggest it.

Comment: I just had to look at this question, as it is getting rare to run into < CF version 7 now and was curious to see what solutions were available.  I think that Railo would be a great option for this problem.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have Windows Server 2008 to hand, but I was able to install ColdFusion 5 on Windows 7 64-bit with very little problem, so you should just go ahead and give it a go (which is always a reasonable approach in these situations).

I have [fully-documented my install experience](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/installing-coldfusion-5-yeah-thats-not.html) on my blog for you (in case it's any help). It's too long to post here.